# Why DependencyProperty.UnsetValue is being passed into Equals()

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I'm developing a simple WPF application. Currently, the application only manages a list of video games in a ComboBox. The game list is serialized to/from an XML file.

The feature that is currently broken is the ability to select a game from the ComboBox which makes it the "active" game to be managed. The active game will be stored as an application setting. To achieve this, I'm using two-way databinding and binding the SelectedItem in the ComboBox to the SelectedGame in the ViewModel.

When I run the application and select an item from the ComboBox, I get a null reference exception on the Game.Equals(Game other) method. While debugging, I saw that DependencyProperty.UnsetValue is being passed as the argument to the overriden Game.Equals(object obj) method which causes `obj as Game` to make obj null.

I don't understand why Equals is being called in the first place when all I'm doing is selecting an item from the ComboBox value, so I'm guessing it's something native to WPF. The code doesn't seem to hit any other breakpoints before heading to the Equals method, so I'm not even sure how to debug the issue. I also don't understand where DependencyProperty.UnsetValue is coming from. I'm just utterly lost here and would appreciate any insight, including how I can debug this further.

**EDIT:** As Glen alluded to, Equals must be called by some underlying component of WPF. My solution, at least for now, was to simply add a null check to my Equals override.

**Model Class**

```
public class Game : IEntity, IEquatable<Game>
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ExecutablePath")]
    public string ExecutablePath { get; set; } 

    public Game(string name, string executablePath)
    {
        Name = name;
        ExecutablePath = executablePath;
    }

    private Game() { } // Required for XML serialization.

    public bool Equals(Game other)
    {
        return Name.EqualsIgnoreCase(other.Name);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Game);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class GamesViewModel
{
    // The GameRepository retrieves the game collection from the XML file.
    private readonly GameRepository _gameRepository;

    public ObservableCollection<Game> Games
    {
        get { return new ObservableCollection<Game>(_gameRepository.Items); }
    }

    public Game SelectedGame
    {
        get { return Settings.Default.ActiveGame; }
        set
        {
            if (!Settings.Default.ActiveGame.Equals(value))
            {
                Settings.Default.ActiveGame = value;
                Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
    }

    public GamesViewModel()
    {
        _gameRepository = RepositorySingletons.GameRepository;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ENBOrganizer.UI.Views.GamesView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ENBOrganizer.UI.ViewModels" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:GamesViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="GamesComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Games}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGame}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0,0,0" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Your Equals method is pretty lazy.  You should be able to handle this without throwing a NRE.

Comment: I'm fine with a null check. I just want to understand why null is being passed in in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `SelectedItem` changes for your `ComboBox` from the view, you will find your source property (`SelectedGame`) may get set twice, once with a value of `null` (as the previous item is no longer selected), and then once for the newly selected item.

If you have code that relies on the object not being null, the way this is typically handled is using a simple null value check:

```
if (value != null)
{
    // Code that relies on value not being null
}
```

Comment: At this point, I don't really have code that specifically relies on a null check.  I may need that in the future, but for early development purposes, I only have 2 games in the ComboBox, so my selection will never be null.

Might you know why the Equals method is being called at all when all I'm doing is selecting an item in the ComboBox?

Comment: That was my first guess. I set a breakpoint on the setter of the SelectedGame property, but the Equals method threw an exception before the setter was even hit.

Comment: Object.Equals is used for many different things in .NET behind the scenes and overriding that method should be done with great care. See [this guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx)